# Looping through a range of dates for comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that records expenditures in this manner:

```
expenditures = [
    (date(2019, 11, 16), 100, 'Transport'),
    (date(2019, 11, 15), 100, 'Transport'),
    (date(2019, 11, 16), 100, 'Transport'),
    (date(2019, 11, 10), 100, 'Transport'),
    ]
```

In each tuple are the date of expenditure, amount and expenditure type. I'm required to print the expenditure type required and over the range of dates specified. For example, i have to print out only tuples containing the expenditure type "Transport" and over the range of dates of 16 to 15 November. I have no problems printing those of the specified type, or expenditures belonging to today. However i am having problem printing over a range of dates. How can i print only entries matching my specified range of dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looping over them and comparing to start and end dates that you set beforehand:

```
from datetime import date

expenditures = [(date(2019, 11, 16), 100, 'Transport'), (date(2019, 11, 15), 100, 'Transport'), (date(2019, 11, 16), 100, 'Transport'), (date(2019, 11, 10), 100, 'Transport')]

start = date(2019, 11, 15)
end = date(2019, 11, 16)

for expenditure in expenditures:
    if end >= expenditure[0] >= start:
        print(expenditure)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Don't know why i didn't consider your method and overcomplicated the solution trying to use For loop, your method's way simpler